# How do I sign up to Superuser with my Stack Exchange OpenID?

Tags: support, stackexchange, login

It sounds like a simple question, right? If you have an existing StackExchage user, you'll want to sign up to SuperUser with it. But there isn't an option to do that in the sign up page:
[image: No option for SX]

I found a work around by signing up to another site on the StackExchange network and some how when I came back to SuperUser I was signed in...

Comment: I wonder if that was recently dropped from the signup page (used to be there).  I also recently signed up for another SE site with a similar experience.  I created an account from scratch but was then recognized and my profile was copied over.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yeah, I've signed up for a dozen SX sites with my SX user and the process was always the same. Superuser is the first site that was different.

Answer (score 4):

The "sign up page" that you show is accessed by clicking, naturally,
on "sign up":

[image: sign up/log in]

"Sign up" means "create a brand new account". 
If you already have a Stack Exchange (OpenID) account,
you don't want to do that; you just want to "log in":

[image: login window]

Comment: fwiw the signup/login link text are now replaced by "join the community" http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260153/upcoming-login-changes-stage-2-and-the-new-ui-now-live

Comment: @Sathya: Yes and no.  If you are actively logged in to Stack Exchange, and you go to a site (or "community") that you haven't participated in yet, you get "join this community".  But if you're not logged in at all, you get the "sign up"/"log in" links.  I made the above screen shots after I saw Coomie's question (less than 4 hours ago) by firing up an incognito browser window; I presume I would have gotten the same result if I had logged out.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying that,